# Use pure virtual methods in an abstract class

Tags: c++

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class A{
public:
    virtual void test1() = 0;
    virtual std::string test2() = 0;
};

class B : public A{

public:
     void test1(){
       std::cout << A::test2() << " World";
    }
};
class C : public B{
public:
     std::string test2(){
        return "hello";
    }
};
class C1 : public B{
public:
     std::string test2(){
        return "Sup";
    }
};

#endif // TEST_H
```

I have an interface A with only pure virtual methods. I have an abstract class that wants to implement `test1` and use `test2` for implementing `test1`.

Now C and C1 and my concrete classes that implement `test2`

But I can't do `std::cout << A::test2() << " World";` in class B

> error: cannot call member function 'virtual std::string A::test2()'
>   without object

How would I do something like this in c++?

Comment: `A` and `B` are not related at all. So you cannot do that. To be able to do this `B` needs to inherit from `A`, I am not sure though how that fits in with your design.

Comment: For a class to implement the interface of `A` it needs to actually _inherit_ from `A`.

Comment: Yes it was a typo I am sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't get hung up on pure virtual versus virtual. Both of the functions declared in `A` are virtual, and you can just treat them as such. So `B`'s implementation of `test1` should simply call `test2`. No `A::` qualifier. That makes a virtual call, and will end up in the most-derived version of `test2`, i.e., the one defined in `C` or `C1`, depending on the type of the object. After I removed the `A::` from `A::test2()`, the following code works (as it should):

```
int main() {
    C c;
    c.test1();
    C1 c1;
    c1.test1();
    return 0;
}

[work]$ g++ test.cpp
[work]$ ./a.out
hello WorldSup World[work]$
```

Yes, you should add a `\n` to the output. `<g>`

Answer (score 2):

Your `class B` needs to inherit from `class A`.

```
class B: public A ...
```

Of course, calling `A::test2()` won't work, since that class is not implemented - it has no body. You could solve that by ALSO implementing it in class A, like this:

```
std::string A::test2() { return "some string"; }
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be a inline pure virtual function? inline pure virtual functions are not allowed by the standard. You need to define it outside the class body.

Comment: Really? I've never used "implemented pure virtuals", but I thought you could inline them. But I will edit it.

Comment: I am so confused right now. Could you make it more clear what I have to do?

Comment: If you want to use `A::test2()` in `B`, then you need to implement `A::test2()` so that it has a real function - calling a pure virtual function won't work. If you want to call "the current derived `test2`" then you should not have `A::`. And no matter which, you do need to derive class B from class A.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use explicit scope qualification if you want a virtual call. Using `A::test2`  will attempt to call `A::test2`, without dynamic dispatch. And this, in turn, will fail to link because `A::test2` has no implementation.

Comment: So what you are saying is that I just call test2(); instead of A::test2(); ? I get the same result.

Comment: When actually trying this I get completely different results from you. In particular, your initial code compiles but fails to link (linker complains it can't find implementation of A::test2). If I remove the A::, it compiles and runs correctly. So either you're using a very buggy compiler, or you didn't actually post the code you're using. Do you have a stray `static` somewhere?

Comment: Okay wow hmm. I used GCC 4.8 which throws some errors. But it compiles fine in clang.

Comment: @CharlesBailey True, I found that out too. Fixed the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The error message implies that, when you compiled it, `B` did not inherit from `A`, so there was no object of type `A` to call the member function on. The code you've posted gives me a different error: that `A::test2` is not defined.

Almost certainly, you want to call the function virtually (i.e. call the final override in `C` or `C1` or whatever). In that case don't qualify it at all:

```
std::cout << test2() << std::endl;
```

Your code tries to specifically call the version declared in `A`, rather than any override. If that's actually what you want (which I doubt), then that function would need to be defined:

```
std::string A::test2() {
    return "I'm a pure virtual function. Why are you calling me?";
}
```

Note that, due to a quirk in the language, pure virtual functions can't be defined inside the class definition; this definition will have to go outside the class.